# Is condensation on the outside of a custom water cooling loop an issue?

Tags: cooling, computer-building, water-cooling

I recently built my first custom water cooling loop (never done any water cooling before) with copper pipes, and have gathered a bunch of comments from know-it-alls, suggesting various doomsday scenarios for my computer. One of them is that since I chose metal pipes, I'll have issues with condensation forming inside the case. I'm not deep into physics or chemistry, but my hypothesis is:

> As long as the tubes are warmer than the surrounding air and the relative humidity is "normal" (indoor climate), there will be no condensation.

My system has two radiators, one pulling air into the case, and another pushing air out. This means that the air temperature inside the case is slightly warmer as the majority of inlet air goes through a radiator.

Measured temperatures during full use:

- Air outside computer: 24C
- Air inside computer: 28C
- Coolant: 32C
- Outside surface of tubes*: 31C

(* Not a reliable measurement, but within expectation)

What are your thoughts on this? Am I missing something? I do see some condensation *inside* the reservoir, but it's completely sealed.

Comment: Where is the condensation forming in your case (except inside the reservoir)? Do you have air conditioning?

Comment: @TurboJ I haven't discovered any condensation yet, this question is about the **potential risk** of condensation, which some people have pointed out to me. My view is that these people don't know what they're talking about, and I'm looking for advice from someone who does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chances of condensation forming on your system are related to the '[dew point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dew_point)' - the relationship between air humidity & temperature.

You can look up the precise curve it forms on Wikipedia, or you can work on the simple rule of thumb that if your pipes are warmer than the ambient temperature & no condensation is forming on your case, then none will be forming on the pipes either.

Comment: Very helpful! I don't have any means to measure humidity, though I doubt it's above 70-80%. As you suggested, it seems reasonable that condensation would form on the outside of the case before it would form on the inside.